# Running java code with Linux shell, but what process are there?

Tags: java, linux, shell, tomcat, web

I'm trying to run Linux command in a Java application as SpringFramework (MVC pattern). I need a running shell script file on Ubuntu server. So I coded like that as follows:
  running java Application as main Method.

```
public static void connectServcer(){
String host="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
    String user="id";
    String password="pw";
    String[] command = {
            "sh"
            , "/usr/local/bin/runShell.sh"
    };

    System.out.println("cmd run");
    try{

        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected");

        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();

        com.jcraft.jsch.Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
        Process process = r.exec(command);
        process.getInputStream();
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);

        InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
        channel.connect();
        byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
        while(true){
          while(in.available()>0){
            int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
            if(i<0)break;
            System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
          }
          if(channel.isClosed()){
            System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
            break;
          }
          try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
        }
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But this method return error as:

```
cmd run 
Connected
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:485)
    at com.company.utils.Linux.connectServcer(Linux.java:59)
    at com.company.utils.Linux.main(Linux.java:9)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 4 more
```

Can anyone help me? I searched and have been understand the login and code it for a week, I'm a beginner in java.

Comment: is it related with chown command on linux, such as -rxwr--r-- user:userG file.java

Comment: I asked on https://askubuntu.com as same problem that as follows:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/966209/error-running-a-shell-command-from-java-cannot-run-program-sh-createprocess
I appreciation all reply

Comment: You probably want to use `/bin/sh` instead of `sh`.

Comment: @SergeBallesta That's not the problem. The problem is that [the command is not being run on the Ubuntu server at all, but on the Windows client instead](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966209/error-running-a-shell-command-from-java-cannot-run-program-sh-createprocess#comment1546976_966209). (Also, are you sure about `ProcessBuilder` and `$PATH`? On Ubuntu with OpenJDK 8, `sh` works as well as `/bin/sh`--unless I run the app with an empty `$PATH`, then it can't find `sh`.) I could post this info as an answer, but I think the OP wants to know how to make it run on the server, which I don't know.

Comment: @Henry thank you so much for reply, I tried both of them.

Comment: @EliahKagan Yes exactly I wanted make it run on the Ubuntu server. well, but I changed way using shell-script on server and It's working weI deployed on  tomcat server and run java application service.
refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46841247/ffmpeg-program-doesnt-running-on-shell-script-with-java-application

Comment: I guess my code wasn't work on java code because I tried to connect by sftp connection. maybe I have to try by ssh connection for the next step. btw, @EliahKagan thank you very much for many info. Its first time asking by stackoverflow but really feel great from all reply xD. have a good day all.ll :) .